# How to expand the output of GlobalAveragePooling2D() to be suitable for BiSeNet?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6

I am trying to build the BiseNet shown in the figure at "https://github.com/Blaizzy/BiSeNet-Implementation".

When I want to use the GlobalAveragePooling2D() in Keras(tf-backend) to finish the Attention Refined Module in Figure(b), I find the output shape of the  GlobalAveragePooling2D() is not suitable for the next convolution.

I checked out many implementation of BiSeNet code in github, however, most of them use AveragePooling2D(size=(1,1)) instead. But AveragePooling2D(size=(1,1)) is completely non-sense.

So I define a lambda layer to do what I want (The selected code is shown as below). The lambda layer works but seems very ugly:

```
def samesize_globalAveragePooling2D(inputtensor):
    # inputtensor shape:(?, 28,28,32)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(inputtensor) # x shape:(?, 32)
    divide = tf.divide(inputtensor, inputtensor)  # divide shape:(?, 28,28,32)
    x2 = x * divide  # x2 shape:(?, 28,28,32)



global_pool = Lambda(function=samesize_globalAveragePooling2D)(conv_0)
```

Hope to get suggestion to make this lambda to be more graceful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using a lambda layer on tf.reduce_mean.

```
tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1, 2], keep_dims=True))
```